# Print variable with each line of while-read command

Tags: sql, bash, shell, impala

I'm trying to set up a monitoring script that would take all the databases we have, showed tables and done some arithmetics on it.
I have this command:

```
impala-shell -i impalad -q " show databases;" -B  | while read a; do impala-shell -q "show tables in ${a}" -B -i impalad; done
```

That produces following output:

```
Query: show tables in database1
table1
table2
```

How should I format the output to display the database name($a) with each table? I tried echoing it or || but this only prints the database name after displaying all the tables. Or is there a way how to pass the variable to awk?
Desired output would look like this:

```
database1.table1
database1.table2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the output of the `show tables ...` command will have a 1-line header, followed by the list of table names.
You could skip the first line by piping to `tail -n +2`,
and then use another `while` loop to echo the database name and table name pairs in the desired format:

```
impala-shell -i impalad -q " show databases;" -B  | while read a; do
    impala-shell -q "show tables in ${a}" -B -i impalad | tail -n +2 | while read table; do
        echo $a.$table
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
impala-shell -q ... | awk -v db="$a" 'NR > 1 {print db "." $0}'
```

Comment: Or you could use sed as below :

Comment: Impala-shell -q ... |  sed s/^/$a/

Comment: Perhaps you mean `sed "s/^[[:blank:]]*/$a./"`